# How to identify Html and Controller completed loading in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-material

Hi,

I am displaying an unsaved changes popup when user enters something and changing his route to another page without saving data.

I used $watch to identify data change event and checking form is dirty or not. If form is dirty I am displaying unsaved changes popup.

My issue is onload some of the forms are become dirty. Unsaved changed popup is displaying user is not done any change also.

I have two approaches to resolve this issue:

1. $watch should execute once html and controller is completes loading.
2. I have to identify an event that html and controller is completes loading.

I used `angular.element(document).ready(function () {});` to identify document loaded event. It is not working. It is executing first time of the page load.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: do you use `$dirty` in your forms? do you ever set them to be dirty with `$setDirty()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, every time your controller will load, **init function** will fire and will set the form state to untouched and pristine :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('Controller1', function ($scope) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        // $setPristine() sets the form's $pristine state to true, 
        // the $dirty state to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class. 
        // Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
        $scope.form.$setPristine();

        //Sets the form to its untouched state.
        $scope.form.$setUntouched();
    }
    $scope.init();
})
.controller('Controller2', function ($scope) {
    $scope.init = function () {

        // $setPristine() sets the form's $pristine state to true, 
        // the $dirty state to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class. 
        // Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
        $scope.form.$setPristine();

        //Sets the form to its untouched state.
        $scope.form.$setUntouched();
    }

    $scope.init();

});
```